# How to save the result of a SQL query in a variable in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I want to try to save the result of this query (I want to get the value of the primary key) into a variable in c# of a MDB database but I don't know how I can do it:

```
SELECT @@identity FROM Table
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
int variable;

    variable = cmd.CommandText("SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM TABLE");
```

PD: It isn't all the code, I have a problem only with this part.

Comment: Read about `ExecutScalar()`

Comment: generally speaking, you EXECUTE your query, which returns a statement handle, from which you fetch one or more rows of result data.

Comment: What object is cmd? IDbCommand has a CommandText property, but no method by that name.

Comment: The ExecuteScalar() works <3 Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it complete code? You just created command object, but didn't open the connection and did not run the command.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM TABLE", conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            newID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM TABLE",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
```